# Find tags that have a CSS field explicitly set

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Is it possible to iterate over every tag in an HTML page looking for tags that have a certain CSS property explicitly set?

In a way:

```
for element in elements {
 if element has CSS.background-image {
   CSS.background-image = something;
 }
}
```

EDIT: Ideally I'm looking for a pure JS solution (no jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

if you are okay with using jquery then check

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('background-imae') == 'something';
});
```

it will give you set of Divs which have a specific background image

For pure js solution check [this](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html)

```
var xx = document.querySelectorAll("div,span");

for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) 
{
    if ( xx[ i ].style.backgroundImage = '' )
    {
     //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Or you can filter by checking for styles like [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have specified that I was looking for a pure JS solution though. Also I'm looking for a solution that finds *any* background-image CSS. I guess that could be achieved with `if ... == ""` though.

Comment: The JS solution actually works but it only works if the element has the CSS background-image inline. It works on a google search page but doesn't work for example on the icons on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_filter.asp where the background-image comes from a class property.

Comment: @Juicy In that case, you will also need to check for those classes which are supplying this background image to the element something like `document.querySelectorAll("div.class1,div.class2");` in addition to the above given code

Comment: I understand if this is not feasible but is there not a way to search for *all* elements? I'm writing a greasemonkey script I want to apply to all pages I visit, so I won't be able to predict class names...

Answer (score 1):

complete reference for Iteration.
[Find tags that have a CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative native way to do it.

```js
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('[style]'));
styledElems = elems.filter(function( elem ){
  return elem.style.background;
})
// you don't the rest. just needed to show that it works
.map( function( elem ){
  return elem.className || elem.tagName;  
});
stackLog( styledElems );

function stackLog( val ){
  document.querySelector('#console').innerHTML += JSON.stringify( val, 0, 2 );
}
```

```html
<!-- You can ignore this html, it's just to have something to test with -->
<section class="thing">
 <header class="thing__header">
  <h3 class="thing__header-heading" style="background:red">Thing Heading</h3>
 </header>
 <div class="thing__content">
  <p class="thing__content-paragraph first" style="background:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius doloremque laborum sapiente libero autem necessitatibus</p>
  <p class="thing__content-paragraph second" style="color:red">
   blanditiis quisquam doloribus dolor molestias corporis a quam eum nisi
  </p>
 </div>
 <footer class="thing__footer">
  <p>ea voluptate, praesentium iste saepe.</p>
 </footer>
</section>
<pre id="console"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

If you need to check all your page the nodeList will be very big. Try to search for an specific class, like `.myElement` instead a `div`. you can fetch all your page with `*` too, but, **Avoid it if you can.**

Be careful with colors, colors will be return as rgb instead hex.

```js
var elementNodeList =  document.querySelectorAll('*'); // get a node List of element of your choice.

var filteredElements = Array.prototype.filter.call(elementNodeList, function (node) {

    var getCompoundStyle = window.getComputedStyle(node);

    return getCompoundStyle.getPropertyValue('property-name') === 'specifiedProperty';
});
```

Your filteredItems will be inside filteredElements variable.